# How set a GroupBox height to size a window, if content is larger heigh, then need show ScrollViewer

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to have GroupBox height  to size a window and if content is larger height, then show ScrollViewer. But it set size to size content or MaxHeight (if it set).

```
<StackPanel>
  <GroupBox>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <StackPanel>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I found if replace the outer StackPanel to DockPanel it will work.

```
 <DockPanel>
  <GroupBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <StackPanel>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
```